# UpdatePanel support in SharePoint Visual Web Part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, updatepanel

Does SharePoint 2013 supports `<asp:UpdatePanel>` inside a visual web part? The issue is when I am filling the details in Web Part controls and if I leave the web part idle for 30 secs or more, the page refresh on any control event. Any suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes SharePoint 2013 supports the

Please try with following and update the updatepanel in .cs when populate the controls in it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
Your controls here
    </ContentTemplate>
</<asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I already tried above but no luck.

Comment: can please post your code